# Как замедлить выполнение программы на Python?

Tags: python

У меня есть программа:

```
name = input("Как тебя зовут? ")
print("Привет, ", name)
```

Я хочу чтобы после input() была пауза в одну секунду, а потом выводилась print(). Такое вообще возможно сделать на Python?

Answer (score 5):

используйте библиотеку `time` и функцию оттуда `sleep()`

```
import time
name = input("Как тебя зовут? ")
time.sleep(1)
print("Привет, ", name)
```